# Replace Changed DOM Nodes dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an external API request that I fetch and resolve and few functions that populate `DOM`, and I would like to write a simple reconciliation algorithm ( *does not need to be efficient nor elegant it is for learning purposes*) that will be able to detect change in incoming data and reflect that to the actual `DOM`

To better illustrate lets say I have initial `request` that populates the `DOM` with some data, and then I will have a function that will periodically hit the endpoint and compare new data to old and if there is change react to it.

So far the only idea that I have is to store a result of initial request into `original` value that has been used to render intial `DOM` and then have `updated` var that will be updated on `setInterval` and if there is difference between two re-render whole thing.

A bit of code:

```
var original;
var updated;

/* Take data original data and render DOM*/
function initialRender() {
  // 1. Fetch data transform and store into original
  // Do the inital render with original data
}

/* Make request every 2sec */
setInterval(function() {
  //1. On each call set updated to new data
  //2. Compare original with updated
  //3. If there are changes call initialRender() or other helper function
}, 2000);
```

Another approach that I have had in mind is to actually get the living `NodeList` from the `DOM` and then re-create whole `DOM` each 2s and if they are different insert updated one.

Edit: Data comes as `JSON` that gets transformed into array of objects which are then used for initial render.

Comment: Well, what you want is basically what React does. Why don't you check their source code? Anyway, you're not giving infor about in which format the data comes from the server to compare it to the actual DOM

Comment: you can use MutationObserver API

Comment: @StéphaneCharron yes I can but I can not see what benefits will I gain from using it since I already rendered everything client side and inserted it into DOM.

Comment: I did check React source code that is why I stated I want plain simple method to compare current DOM with new.

Comment: Any SPA framework will do the job

Comment: @StéphaneCharron I know but as I stated it is learning process. I could have done the same with `React` or `Vue` in no time but I decided to use plain vanila js and code everything my self. Thus I don't need performance nor benefits that most of SPA's gives us.

Comment: check Build Your Own AngularJS by Tero Parviainen, I have learned so much

Comment: @ukaric if you don't want to use React, which does the job you want, check differences on a simpler data type, don't relate on DOM nodes, instead, compare two objects and find the diffs.

Comment: @ukaric yes jsondiffpatch is a good tool for json diff